# charts drawing over charts, old charts remain

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Using charts js 2.9.4 I call a function that creates a new chart. So during the application a few charts may get drawn. If I hover and show a tool tip the maps flicker and change back and forth. It seems they are just drawing on the canvas over and over. I tried chart.destroy(); but it didnt help. Is there a way to clean up the old chart?

for example I tried this

```
<div id="wrapper" class="Wrapper"  name="Wrapper"  style="background-color: grey; border:1px  ">
<canvas  id="line-chart" class="Chart"  name="Chart"  </canvas>
</div>
```

.
.
.

```
if (chart) chart.destroy();
 var chart = 
    new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
```

Comment: Please provide the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling multiple charts with the same variable name `var chart` which is why not all are destroying and keep showing up. To resolve this you need to have unique variable names for each chart and destroy each of them separately.